# Correct way to call a method inside a method

Tags: c#

I need to create an application to act as a BMI calculator, that collects a number of attributes, has matching properties to get and set these attribute values and requests a number of methods to calculate specific data such as patient age, max heart rate, target rates and more.

My question is essentially regarding the usage of methods and to see if this usage is correct or improper.

My method to calculate age looks like the following:

```
public int Age()
{
   DateTime Now = DateTime.Today;
   return (Now.Year - DateOfBirth);
}
```

What I am not 100% sure of is if I can now use that method in another method's calculation, such as the following:

```
public int MaxHeartRate()
{
   return (220 - Age());
}
```

I could have used a property to do this as well however, the assignment called for the use of methods to perform the calculation.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I understand the usage between both methods and properties, however I am just unclear on the usage of calling another method inside a method for calculation purposes.

Comment: "I could have used a property to do this as well however, the assignment called for the use of methods to perform the calculation." Ah, crazy assignment specs... I've had stuff that forbade the use of generic collections just because my school didn't think anyone would know how to use them.

Comment: I don't want to be negative or anything, but wouldn't it have been much faster just to test the above than to actually formulate the question (which btw is very well formulated)?

Comment: Haha, I actually did, it works perfectly fine, but as you know, there are a number of ways to get the job done and in some cases just because it works does not mean it should be used that way, hence why I came here to ask for some clarity on the subject ;) Thanks!

Comment: @sfla99: that's the way to go! Again, i didn't mean anything bad, I was just reflecting on the fact that you provided all the necessary code, so it felt that the answer was just an F5 away. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine.

However, you might have a bug here:

```
public int Age() {
    DateTime Now = DateTime.Today;
    return (Now.Year - DateOfBirth);
}
```

It's not clear what `DateOfBirth` is, but if it represents the year of birth as it appears to, what happens if I'm born December 31, 2011, and `DateTime.Now` is January 1, 2012 12:00:00.000 AM?

Also, one point of comment, you'll often see people write your method as

```
public int MaxHeartRate() {
    return (220 - this.Age());
}
```

making it crystal clear that we are invoking the instance method `Age`. Readability is one of the single most important features of writing good code.

Comment: Thank you all for your insanely quick response! Its truly appreciated.  The above worked perfectly fine, I just really needed some clarity on the usage of methods within a method and you all have set me straight. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: I should have pointed out that DateOfBirth is a property passed in from the program and is set as a type int simply EG: 1986, for this purpose I only needed to use (Now.Year - DateOfBirth), lastly and unfortunately I was not allowed to the this.Age() yet in class.

Answer (score 1):

straight answer is yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your usage is correct.  This is pretty standard actually, as you can only call methods from within other methods.  The only thing I would double check on is:

```
return (Now.Year - DateOfBirth);
```

I don't know if this will return an int or not due to the DateofBirth being a datetime.  You might want to just check over that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (and should!) use the `Age` method in places where you're using that calculated value to calculate others.

Your logic for calculating age is not correct, though.  `DateTime.Today` returns a `DateTime` object representing (as of this writing) September 16, 2011 at 12:00:00 AM.  `DateTime.Today.Year` would therefore return 2011.  If I was born in February of 1984, and assuming `DateOfBirth` is the year I was born, this method will always return 27 when you run it in 2011, until you hit January 1, 2012 at which point it will start returning 28.

Don't just compare years--compare the actual dates and then pull out the Year part of the `TimeSpan` difference between them.

Comment: The usage of DateTime = Now, is allowing me to use Now.Year in the calculation, I guess its an extra step, I could have cone the day/month/year but for the purpose of this exercise, it simply need a small calculation to get the max heart rate, the issue initially was that the example does now get an input from the user for the current year, so I had to use DateTime to base that off their age.

Comment: ``(DateTime.Now - DateOfBirth).Year`` would return the data you want and be mathematically accurate, as long as ``DateOfBirth`` is a ``DateTime``.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are doing is fine, assuming that `DateOfBirth` returns what you want. The function you have defined will always return an `int` since that is the return type you have defined. This means you can use the function `Age()` in any place that expects an integer.

A couple of pointers to help you start out:

- You mentioned this so I think you get it, but in general this might be a candidate for storing in a variable. The way you have it now every time the `Age()` function is called a calculation will be performed. Sometimes this is what you want. It is reasonable here since your age could change, but that is only once a year. You can imagine a really complicated method that does a lot of heavy lifting. You would want to cache the output of that function in a variable.
- You have defined a variable `Now` that just gets `DateTime.Today`. Then you use that to find the year. You can save a step by just putting `DateTime.Today.Year` instead of making a new variable. A minor point.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: My bad! it's been a long week! As mentioned below in the comments, you'd only way this as static if it takes a parameter.

The problem you will have here is that the Age() function is not static, as a result you'd need to create and instance, which for that type of method is not what you want.

If you define Age() as :

```
public static int Age() { }
```

Then you can use it like you have in the MaxHearRate() method

Comment: How do you even know that having it as an instance method is not what he wants?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: `Age`, as declared as a **parameterless** method, clearly needs to be an instance method otherwise it has no way of getting the data that it needs to calculate the age.